# 2013 Publishing Site Template Creation Tutorials or Help?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, publishing-site, template

I'm working on a (my first 2013) Publishing site and am trying to find information or a tutorial on how to add the controls to a custom template. For example, I downloaded the free ShareBoot Template from the BindTuning (http://bindtuning.com/) folks and see the initial page layout when I apply it to my subsite, however, I do not understand what I need to put into the page in order to add webparts or apps to the page.

I get an area to add text to if I add this for example:

```
<div class="col-sm-12>
 <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="200px" InputFieldLabel="Left Content" runat="server" ID="TopContentArea"/>
</div>
```

Do I need something else here:

```
 <PublishingWebControls:**RichHtmlField**
```

In order to add webparts?

I cannot find much info on Microsoft's site, but I think I may be asking the wrong questions since I don't know this 2013 publishing site lingo yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to insert web parts into the field content. Click into the editable area of the page, then look at the Insert tab of the ribbon.

If you are looking for web part zones, then you will need to create a custom layout. On that custom layout, you can add web part zones as you need.

[How to: Create a page layout in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368%28v=office.15%29.aspx)